# How many users and objects can be in an Oracle Database?

Tags: oracle

I wonder if anyone know what can be the biggest existing Oracle databases in the world and how many users (DBA_USERS), objects (DBA_OBJECTS) they can contain?

Is there a scenario when a database contain more than 100 000 users?

For example, as far as I can guess, there can be thousands of users in MySQL database on a webhosting server where each hosting user registered on the hosting website has its own MySQL user. Is there a real-life Oracle databases that are used in a way like this?

Comment: There is a section in The Fine Manual called "Limits ".

Comment: @MichaelKutz sorry, I am a newbie in Oracle, what is 'Fine Manual'?

Comment: Let me get some coffee so i can answer nicely.

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or are you planning to use Oracle in this way? This begs the question: Why? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Colin'tHart I do not use Oracle, but I am starting to work on a software that saves DBA_USERS, DBA_OBJECTS, DBA_ROLES, DBA_SYS_PRIVS, DBA_TAB_PRIVS, DBA_COL_PRIVS to a file and I need to estimate its size.

Answer (score 2):

All Oracle Documentation can be found on-line

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/index.html

It is highly recommended that you read the ["Concepts Guide"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/cncpt/index.html).  If you understand just a tiny bit, it will make you a much better developer/DBA.

For your specific answer, you need to look in the "Database Reference" manual section ["Database Logical Limits"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/logical-database-limits.html#GUID-685230CF-63F5-4C5A-B8B0-037C566BDA76).

> Users and Roles  |  maximum   |   2,147,483,638
>
> Tables | maximum per database | unlimited

## App Design Notes

Web Users are normally stored in a table.

In Oracle :  Users and Schemas are almost synonymous.  This makes the requirement "create an Oracle user for each and every Web User" a very expensive task.... And a dangerous one at that.  (The last thing you want is L33TH4CKR to have his/her own account on your database)